# Asterisk into SSH setup

Tags: centos, voip, asterisk

I'm totally newbie in VoIP subject. But I really need to figure out how to setup Asterisk into a CentOS ssh... The plan is: I have one SSH, will buy a DID number, and want configure the Asterisk in this SSH to use the DID number for receive calls. Only receiving calls. When someone call the DID, it should start  an IVR with DTMF... And save the logs from DTMF into a .txt file... Can someone help-me with this? Posting some answer with some tips to me study or a tutorial link. Or even contact-me, I'm able to pay for this... Thank you...

Comment: Didn't really get what you mean ‘SSH’， do you mean you have a VPS?EC2?  As for VOIP/Asterisk subject, it never goes wrong started with http://www.voip-info.org/

Comment: Yes I have one VPS CentOS... Can you help-me?!

Answer (score 0):

Try read this book

[Asterisk -The future of telephony](http://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEcQFjAE&url=http://book.huihoo.com/pdf/asterisk-the-future-of-telephony/AsteriskTFOT-2.pdf&ei=nWZnULeeBer_4QSJpYDACA&usg=AFQjCNF_RjsRDNwFDK0CkAjoGQkaA846tQ&sig2=bPLhS_iF6n3gcsV-QH1Vqg)

If you want do it yourself, you have do following:

1) install asterisk [using yum](http://www.asterisk.org/downloads/yum)

2) setup sip extension [sip.conf](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+sip.conf)

3) setup dialplan [dialplan introduction](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Dialplan+Introduction)

4) create AGI script for save to file [AGI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI). Sure you need some programming experience for do that.

Or hire some freelancer to do work for you at

http://freelancer.com